# Nextjs Query Image not being Displayed

Tags: image, next.js, fetch

I am trying to transfer image that is selected by the user to another route by query in useRouter, and after handling the image in the other route I entered it to Image component after doing the necessary things, but the image is not being displayed for some reason(no error occur).

Because there is no specific error I tried asking chatgpt to know the problem but it just enhance the code by using fetch and convert the file to blob then to dataurl depend on what chatgpt that should solve the problem, but nothing was solved.
This is my current code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      handleFileUpload(image);
    }
  }, [image]);

  const handleFileUpload = async (imageURL) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(imageURL);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      setFiles((previous) => [
        ...previous,
        <div className="bg-white rounded-lg h-60 w-36 hover:brightness-95 shadow-md">
          <div className="bg-gray-400 flex h-3/4 rounded-t-lg">
            <Image
              src={dataURL}
              alt="Story"
              fit
            />
          </div>
        </div>,
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    }
  };
```